# Parse Cloud result object is empty

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I got this problem yesterday, couldn't resolved it myself.

Here is my parse.com cloud code :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getWorkerInfo", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  userQuery.equalTo(request.params.userObjectId);
  userQuery.select("firstName", "lastName", "username");
  userQuery.first({
    success : function(result){
      var currentUser = {
        "firstName" : result.firstName,
        "lastName" : result.lastName,
        "username" : result.username
      };
      response.success(currentUser);
    },
    error : function(error){
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

and result to chrome dev tools command :

```
result : {}
```

this code for using result from first code wrote this question :

```
function get(userObjectId) {
    Parse.Cloud.run("getWorkerInfo", { "userObjectId" : userObjectId }, {
        success: function(result){
            return result;
        }
        ,
        error : function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

I also changed to response data - user query directly.
Response action is okay.

But Couldn't retrieved that itself :

```
result = ParseUser {_objCount: 2, className: "_User", id: "iNneJil9XW"}
```

What I missing, and can I find answer this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Clark, there's a lot going on in this question.  Try hard coding the result just to make sure the execution flow/path is correct and the environment is set up correctly.  For example,

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getWorkerInfo", function(request, response) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  userQuery.equalTo(request.params.userObjectId);
  userQuery.select("firstName", "lastName", "username");
  userQuery.first({
    success : function(result){
      response.success("1234");
    },
    error : function(error){
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```